# Does the principle of explosion follow from the stability axioms?

Tags: logic

I am supposed to prove the [drinker paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox) - that is, the formula $$\lnot\forall_x\lnot (Px\to \forall_xPx)$$ for some relation symbol $P$. I know that it follows from the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), which corresponds to the axiom $$\lnot A\to A\to B$$for any formulas $A$ and $B$. However, the problem asks to prove the drinker paradox based only on the rules of natural deduction and the stability axioms, i.e. by assuming $$\forall_\vec x(\lnot\lnot R\vec x\to R\vec x)$$
for each relation symbol $R$. Thus, I am wondering if the principle of explosion follows from the stability axioms. Please note that I am a beginner in logic.

Comment: You're unlikely to get a useful answer because your question is missing a lot of important context.

Consider posting the task/problem exactly as worded, giving as much context as you possibly can (Which logical rules are you allowed to use? Which textbook? Which course? etc.)

Comment: @Z.A.K. Thank you for the suggestion! I am in lecture now, but I will make an edit later.

Comment: @Z.A.K. The course is based on the book "Proofs and Computations" by Schwichtenberg and Wainer (Cambridge 2012). So far, we have talked about natural deduction. The problem asks to prove the formula $$\lnot\forall_x\lnot (Px\to \forall_xPx)$$ for some relation symbol $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows, let $P$ denote a relation symbol in your language. Your task is to prove $\neg \forall x. \neg (Px \rightarrow \forall y. Py)$, and you are allowed to assume $\forall x. \neg\neg Rx \rightarrow Rx$ for any relation symbol $R$, but not allowed to use the principle of explosion.

Remark: Note the wording! Any *relation symbol*, not any *formula*. If you were allowed to assume stability for any formula, this would be a different, much easier task. Nonetheless, even under these strict restrictions, the answer to the question is positive: It is indeed possible to derive the drunkard sentence (as stated above) under these restrictions, although it took me a while to figure out how.

I'll give a derivation in a common natural deduction system. I'll leave it up to you to translate it into the precise natural deduction system used by Schwichtenberg and Wainer.

We have to prove $\neg \forall x. \neg (Px \rightarrow \forall y. Py)$. We will do this by assuming $\forall x. \neg (Px \rightarrow \forall y. Py)$, and reaching a contradiction. We will additionally freely assume $\forall x. \neg\neg Px \rightarrow Px$, which we're entitled to do, since $P$ is a relation symbol according to the problem statement.

1. Assume $\forall x. \neg\neg Px \rightarrow Px$.
2. Assume $\forall x. \neg (Px \rightarrow \forall y. Py)$.
3. Assume $Pt$.
4. Assume $\neg Py$.
5. Have $\neg (Py \rightarrow \forall z. Pz)$ from assumption 2 by universal elimination.
6. Assume $Py$.
7. Assume $\neg Pz$.
8. Have a contradiction from $Py$ (assumption 6) and $\neg Py$ (assumption 4).
9. Have $\neg\neg Pz$ from 8 by negation introduction, discharging assumption 7.
10. Have $\neg\neg Pz \rightarrow Pz$ from assumption 1 by universal elimination.
11. Have $Pz$ from 9 and 10 by implication elimination.
12. Have $\forall z. Pz$ from 11 by universal introduction.
13. Have $Py \rightarrow \forall z. Pz$ from 12 by implication introduction, discharging assumption 6.
14. Have a contradiction from $Py \rightarrow \forall z. Pz$ (13) and $\neg(Py \rightarrow \forall z. Pz)$ (5).
15. Have $\neg\neg Py$ from 14 by negation introduction, discharging assumption 4.
16. Have $\neg\neg Py \rightarrow Py$ from assumption 1 by universal elimination.
17. Have $Py$ from 15 and 16 using universal elimination.
18. Have $\forall y. Py$ from 17 using universal introduction.
19. Have $Pt \rightarrow \forall y. Py$ from 18 using implication introduction, discharging assumption 3.
20. Have $\neg(Pt\rightarrow \forall y. Py)$ from assumption 2 using universal elimination.
21. Have a contradiction from $Pt \rightarrow \forall y. Py$ (19) and $\neg(Pt\rightarrow \forall y. Py)$ (20).
22. Have $\neg\forall x. \neg (Px \rightarrow \forall y. Py)$ from 21 by negation introduction, discharging assumption 2.

Note that we do not have to discharge assumption 1 (we're allowed to assume it freely as per the text of the problem), and all other assumptions have been discharged by an appropriate rule. Hence, we have a proof of $\neg\forall x. \neg (Px \rightarrow \forall y. Py)$, which is what we need (up to renaming the bound variable $y$).

Answer (score 1):

We can use the stability axiom to show explosion $\bot \to \varphi$ for all formulas $\varphi$.
The proof works by induction on the depth of the formula $\varphi$:

If the depth is $0$, then we must have $\varphi = \bot$ or $\varphi = Rx$ for some relation $R$ and term-vector $x$. The first case then obviously works out.

To prove $\bot \to Rx$ we assume $H : \bot$ and try to show $R x$. Actually, by the stability axiom for relations it suffices to show $\neg \neg Rx$, so we can further assume $\neg Rx$ and are now trying to produce a proof of $\bot$. But we have this by the assumption $H$.

For the induction step, we know that the depth is $> 0$. We therefore have the following cases:

- $(\varphi = \varphi_1 \land \varphi_2)$ We can assume $H : \bot$ and must show $\varphi_1 \land \varphi_2$. Since $\varphi_k$ has smaller depth than $\varphi$, we know by the induction hypothesis that $\bot \to \varphi_k$. Combined with $H$ this gives $\varphi_k$ for $k = 1,2$ and $\varphi_1 \land \varphi_2$ then easily follows.
- $(\varphi = \varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2)$ Similar to above.
- $(\varphi = \varphi_1 \to \varphi_2)$ Again, similar to the above.
- $(\varphi = \forall x : \phi$ or $\varphi = \exists x : \phi)$ By the induction hypothesis we have $\bot \to \phi$. This suffices to show both $\bot \to (\forall x : \phi)$ and $\bot \to (\exists x : \phi)$. $~~\Box$

The above proof contains a more general and quite useful result: In minimal logic, any closed formula $\varepsilon$ is explosive for all formulas (i.e. for all $\varphi$ we have $\varepsilon \to \varphi$) if and only if it is explosive on the atomic formulas. So we only need to check its explosiveness on atomic formulas.

Anyways, from $\bot \to \varphi$ we can of course conclude $\color{blue}{\neg \alpha \to \alpha \to \varphi}$ for all formulas $\alpha, \varphi$ and we will use this in the below proof of the drinker paradox.

---

Here is a derivation of $\neg \forall_x \neg (P x \to \forall_y P y)$ from the stability axiom.

Assume $H : \forall_x \neg (P x \to \forall_y P y)$ and try to reach a contradiction.

Let's first show that we have $\neg \neg Py$ for any $y$. So assume $\neg Py$, then by $\color{blue}{\text{the above}}$ $\color{blue}{\text{explosion}}$ $\color{blue}{\text{principle}}$ we have $Py \to \forall_z Pz$. But this contradicts $H$, so we can indeed conclude $\neg \neg P y$.

We then get $\forall_y P y$ by the stability axiom and the fact that $y$ was arbitrary in the above.

But with this, we can now take just any $a$$^{(\ast)}$ and obviously have $Pa \to \forall_y Py$. This finally gives us the contradiction to $H$ we desired.

---

$(\ast)$ Note that depending on the details of the used deduction rules and semantics, the drinker paradox should really be written $\forall_a \neg \forall_x \neg (P x \to \forall_y P y)$ to make sure that we have this $a$. Without the $\forall_a$ the paradox can atually be wrong, if we allow empty models.